Curl function not working in Apache Nifi using the ExecuteStreamCommand and --data-raw
I am having a problem with using the ExecuteStreamCommand with a curl command using the --data-raw tag. This tag allows you to control the number of results.  When I run this command in the terminal it works and return 1 result:
curl -X POST "https://mpstats.io/api/wb/get/category?d1=2023-01-01&d2=2023-01-31&path=1111" --header "X-Mpstats-TOKEN: 1111 " --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw "{\"startRow\":0,\"endRow\":1,\"filterModel\":{},\"sortModel\":[{\"colId\":\"revenue\",\"sort\":\"desc\"}]}"

However, when I run it as an ExecuteStreamCommand in NiFi, it returns 100 results, instead of 1.
I tried to use InvokeHTTP, but the result did not change. I don't understand how to enter the startRow and endRow parameters to make it work.
